# Divide time intervals to each hour and assign the values proportionally

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I’m trying to make hourly duration from data like this

```
df1=data.frame(Start=c("18:12","18:42","20:12","22:30"),
               End=c("18:30","20:00","22:30","22:36"),
               Duration (hour)=c(0.3,1.3,2.3,0.1))
```

| Start | End | Duration (hour) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18:12 | 18:30 | 0.3 |
| 18:42 | 20:00 | 1.3 |
| 20:12 | 22:30 | 2.3 |
| 22:30 | 22:36 | 0.1 |

example: at 18-19 duration=0.6 because 0.3 +(18:42-19:00)
at 19-20 = 1, 20-21 = 0.8(theres nothing 20:00-20:12(0.2)), 21-22 = 1, 22-23= 0.6(stop at 22:36)

my expected like this

| clock | Duration (hour) |
| --- | --- |
| 18to19 | 0.6 |
| 19to20 | 1 |
| 20to21 | 0.8 |
| 21to22 | 1 |
| 22to23 | 0.6 |

Comment: Having trouble with your logic. For example, why does 18:42 - 19:00 = 0.3?

Comment: It‘s 18 minutes. And that‘s 0.3 of a full hour (60 minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution entirely in `dplyr`. I converted the times to `datetime` object and created a sequence between `Start` and `End` with 1-min interval.

Then if the next hour at minute 0 is present, I count the row in the previous hour as well, otherwise, just count the number of rows (refer to `mutate(val = if_else(...`;). This has a flaw since if we don't have the full hour, and yet have the start of the hour or start of the next hour, then we will count the previous hour and the next hour while we should not do so. Hence, I check if the full hour is present or if the start of this hour and the next are not present, if so I'd just deduct 1, otherwise I deduct 2 from the sum.

I created a dataframe to show every possible case.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Start = c("06:16","07:36","08:18", "18:12",
                            "18:42","20:12","22:30", "23:15"),
                  End = c("06:42","08:18","10:00","18:30",
                          "20:00","22:30","22:36", "23:30"), 
                  Duration = c(0.433,0.7,1.7,0.3,1.3,2.3,0.1, 0.25))

#>   Start   End Duration
#> 1 06:16 06:42    0.433
#> 2 07:36 08:18    0.700
#> 3 08:18 10:00    1.700
#> 4 18:12 18:30     0.30
#> 5 18:42 20:00     1.30
#> 6 20:12 22:30     2.30
#> 7 22:30 22:36     0.10
#> 8 23:15 23:30     0.25
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(Start:End, ~strptime(.x, format = "%H:%M"))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(data.frame(time=seq.POSIXt(.$Start,.$End,by="1 min"))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Hour = hour(time), Minute = minute(time)) %>% 
  arrange(time) %>% 
  mutate(val = if_else(lead(Hour, default = Hour[n()]) == Hour + 1 & 
                       lead(Minute, default = Minute[n()]) == 0, 2, 1)) %>% 
  group_by(Clock = Hour) %>% 
  summarise(Duration = if_else( (sum(val) %in% c(61, 1)) | 
                                (all(Minute != 0) & all(diff(Minute) == 1)), 
                           sum(val)-1, sum(val)-2) / 60) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(Duration != 0) %>% 
  mutate(Clock = paste(Clock, Clock + 1, sep = "to"))
```

```
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    Clock  Duration
#>    <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1 6to7      0.433
#>  2 7to8      0.4  
#>  3 8to9      1    
#>  4 9to10     1    
#>  5 18to19    0.6  
#>  6 19to20    1    
#>  7 20to21    0.8  
#>  8 21to22    1    
#>  9 22to23    0.6  
#> 10 23to24    0.25
```

Comment: im trying to my df and the output "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument"

Comment: @FadhilDzikri You probably need to ask another question and share a reproducible example of your datset.

Answer (score 2):

Below I create dummy variables for each hour using a custom function `calc_time()` inside `dplyover::over()`. We can wrap the custom function in `sum` inside `dplyr::summarise()` to get the total count per hour and then we only need to `pivot_longer()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyover)

calc_time <- function(hour, start, end) {
  hour_start <- strptime(paste0(hour, ":00"), format = "%H:%M") 
  hour_end   <- strptime(paste0(hour + 1, ":00"), format = "%H:%M") 
  
  started_this_hour <- start >= hour_start & start < hour_end
  ended_this_hour   <- end <= hour_end & end >= hour_start
  
  started_before <- start < hour_start & end > hour_start
  
  case_when(started_this_hour & ended_this_hour ~ as.numeric((end - start)/60),
            started_before & ended_this_hour ~ as.numeric((end - hour_start)/60),
            started_this_hour ~ as.numeric((hour_end - start)/60),
            started_before ~ 1,
            TRUE ~ 0)
}

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Start, End), \(x) strptime(x, format = "%H:%M"))) %>% 
  summarise(over(18:22, # specify the hours you want to loop over, max is 0:23
              ~ sum(calc_time(.x, Start, End)),
              .names = "{x}to{x+1}"
              )
         ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = "clock",
               values_to = "Duration (hour)")

#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   clock  `Duration (hour)`
#>   <chr>              <dbl>
#> 1 18to19               0.6
#> 2 19to20               1  
#> 3 20to21               0.8
#> 4 21to22               1  
#> 5 22to23               0.6
```

Data from OP

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Start = c("18:12","18:42","20:12","22:30"),
  End   = c("18:30","20:00","22:30","22:36"),
  Duration = c(0.3,1.3,2.3,0.1)
  )
```

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of {dplyover} which is not on CRAN.

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thankyyou very much @TimTeaFan, its so helpfull for me, if u'd like to help me again, please answer my quest on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75647558/how-to-manipulating-dataframe-like-this

Comment: Tim, you may wanna check dplyover and the functions/Locale that it masks/alters.

Comment: @M--: Do you mean specifically `grDevices::over()`?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure what happened, but after loading it, when I use `arrange`, it orders lowercase letters before uppercase. I am on my phone rn, can try to show an example later. But basically if I have a column with `A, b, a, B, b`, it sorts as `a, A, b, b, B` while without loading your package it would be `A, a, B, b, b`.

Comment: @M--: That's interesting and something I need to look into. In my current locale `A, b, a, B, b` is somehow arranged as `A, B, a, b, b` when only loading dplyr and dplyover doesn't change that.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I used `arrange(tolower(col1), col1)`.